# I co-signed for my son's car and he died. I told the bank to come get it and they told me they won't take it

Tags: car, auto-loan

The loan keeps showing up on my credit report. They offered me a pay off but I can't afford to pay it off. I asked the loan company what to do? And they can't give me a answer...

Comment: I recall reading on here recently that you DO NOT want to do a voluntary reposession because that is still a reposession. You want to sell the car and use the money to pay off the loan.

Comment: Isn't there an insurance going with the loan which should take care of paying off the loan in such a case? What country (and state, if relevant) are you in?

Comment: No, loans are rarely if ever insured, at least in the US. The bank is protected (partially) by the lien on the collateral, in this case the car. The borrower can do whatever they like, but there's no reason any insurance company would want to sell you insurance on your borrowing.

Comment: @keshlam Wrong. [Credit Insurance](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/ask-cfpb/what-is-credit-insurance-for-an-auto-loan-en-799/) is most definitely a thing in the US. Why would insurance company want to sell it? It comes with high profit margins since covered events (death, permanent disability) are rarer than people think. The most common event, layoffs, only comes with a deferral. This is often pushed by dealership finance people to less-qualified borrowers who don't have a cushion fund. The UK had a [major scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_protection_insurance) over this.

Comment: @user71659: I haven't seen it. Of course I'm far from being in the target market for it

Comment: Sorry to add to your problems, but one other thing you should check is, who actually owns the car now - simply being a co-signer may not actually grant you ownership of the car, unless that is in the original loan agreement.

Comment: @davidt: ***Good point!*** You might want to consider making that a (partial) answer, since it definitely needs to be checked. If the car was willed to someone else, all you can do is ask if they would be willing to help pay off the remaining loan; you can't exactly sell it out from under them. Lawyer time?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://consumer.ftc.gov/consumer-alerts/2023/11/what-do-if-you-cant-make-car-payments

Answer (score 58):

Condolences on the loss of your son.  Unfortunately, there probably isn't a lot to do here.

A co-signer is equally responsible for repaying the loan as the borrower.  From the finance company's perspective, they'd probably lose money repossessing the car-- most cars depreciate faster than the loan balance declines until close to the end of the loan.  They've got a borrower that is legally responsible for paying off the loan (you) and they think you're likely to be able to pay.  So they're not interested in repossessing the car and taking the loss, they'd rather take the risk that you're going to keep making the monthly payments.

You could sell the car and pay off whatever the difference is between the value of the car and the balance of the loan.  That's likely to be a decently large number though.  Or you could keep making the monthly payments.

It is possible that the finance company would be more willing to repossess the car if they thought you were unwilling to pay.  But that would require actually not paying and dealing with a charged off loan and a repossession on your credit report.  That is probably not something you want to risk.

Comment: Remember, they don't want the car. They want the rest of their money.

Comment: @keshlam - Exactly this. Car finance companies aren't in the business of selling cars, they're in the business of selling loans. The car is merely a tool to get you to take out a loan.

Comment: And to try to enforce your paying the loan, and to recover part of the money should you default on the loan. But foreclosure does only get them part of that money, so they are going to be very unhappy with you if they have to resort to that, which is why it's such a bad thing for your credit rating. If you find you can't afford the car, the responsible thing to do it to sell it yourself and use that money plus as much more as is needed to pay off the loan. Remember, you agreed to this.

Comment: @Valorum No, not always true. The majority of new car loans in US/Canada are by a captive finance company, owned by the automaker. Their goal is to sell cars and receive subsidy from the automaker to offer below-market rates, called a subvented loan. Another function is to lease cars (1/3-1/4 of new car sales). In North America, consumer leases are always closed-end leases (rent with buyout option). Importantly, automakers sponsor these leases to get a supply of used cars. Finance companies have comprehensive remarketing operations to refurbish and distribute these cars.

Comment: The problem is they will probably block sale of the car for less than the loan is worth.

Comment: "Or you could keep making the monthly payments." and keep a car you don't use, that's rapidly depreciating. not many good options in that situation...

Comment: @Joshua That never prevents a sale unless you have no way to borrow money because you can always reduce the value of the loan to the sale price of the car by partially paying the loan.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: People in this situation have a hard time borrowing at a remotely reasonable rate. :(

Comment: @Joshua Then it does not benefit them to sell the car. The payments on the care are likely lower than any other arrangement available.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The loan holder needs to permit the car to be sold, accept the proceeds, and reset the payment amount based on the remaining outstanding (so the remaining loan runtime it the same). But they're being pointlessly obstinate and driving OP into serious financial trouble for a few bucks. They're themselves taking a gamble of a huge loss at this point too.

Comment: The company might be willing to let the OP sell the car and reduce the future payments. It's surely worth asking?

Comment: @user7868 No, a car loan is a secured loan. If the car is sold, they have no asset to repo. It's also beyond their control, as such loans are very often packaged and securitized. You'd have to get a personal loan or other cash (HELOC) then use it to pay off the difference at the time of car sale.

Comment: @user71659: If the car can't be sold for the loan value, the gap value is unsecured. They're better off taking the sell it now offer than not.

Comment: @Joshua They take their sell it now offer and they best they can do at that point is report a charge-off. Or, they hold the debtor to the original deal. If they don't pay, the creditor gets a judgement that allows them to seize assets and garnish their wages for many years. The debtor either pays or they file for bankruptcy, in which case the court seizes their assets and garnishes their wages for many years. So what you say is wrong, the latter options result in more recovery.

Comment: @user71659: Did you even read my comment above?

Comment: @Joshua It makes no sense. You don't need a-priori permission from a _creditor_ (the correct term) to sell your car. You go online, look up the payoff amount, and write a check to them in that amount, they send the title. Again, you're incorrectly assuming you can "convert" a secured loan into a completely different unsecured loan, which isn't generally possible.

Comment: @user71659: You write "isn't generally possible" when it is _a priori_ possible for the creditor to do exactly that.

Comment: @Joshua Again, I clearly explained that loans are very often securitized or have funding mechanisms like [asset-backed notes](https://www.rightnotes.com/en-us/home.html). It's not within the creditor's ability to change the terms of debt held by others.